# What's the maximum likelihood estimation of $\theta$ in this density?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, inference, estimators, sufficient-statistics

Suppose we have a n-sample $X=(X_1,..,X_n)$ with a distribution $f(x,\theta)=exp(\theta - x)\unicode{x1D7D9}_{x \geq \theta}(x)$.

Find the maximum likelihood estimator $T$ of $\theta$ and prove that $T$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

The problem here is that we $\theta$ in the indicator function so I don't know how properly proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: The indicator tells you if $x<\theta$ then the likelihood is zero. Otherwise, the likelihood will be bigger than 0. Hence, you only need to search for the mle for $\theta \leq min(X)$

Comment: @jcken So the function is increasing with respect to $\theta$ therefore $min(X)$ is the mle?